# Xampp violation access

Tags: xampp

anyone can help me as below :

```
10:14:39 AM [main] Initializing Control Panel
10:14:39 AM [main] Windows Version: Windows Server 2003 32-bit
10:14:39 AM [main] XAMPP Version: 1.8.2
10:14:39 AM [main] Control Panel Version: 3.2.1 [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
10:14:39 AM [main] Running with Administrator rights - good!
10:14:39 AM [main] XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xamppx\"
10:14:39 AM [EXCEPTION] Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000
10:14:39 AM [main] Deinitializing Modules
10:14:39 AM [main] Deinitializing Control Panel
```

Comment: Welcome! Would be good to explain the context of the error...

Comment: when i run the xampp s/w, it will not go to xampp control panel .. it just disappeared like that

Comment: anyone help .. im headache solving myself

Comment: I do not know the software, but the "Access violation" error message certainly sounds like a bug. Did you check known bugs that may be similar?

Comment: i have no idea .. i can't even go into xampp control panel but the installation s/w succeed

Answer (score 0):

At StackOverflow, there is a question giving a possible solution as part of the question, not as an answer. It is closed as off topic, but it could be the right solution.

[Access violation error while using XAMPP? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037628/access-violation-error-while-using-xampp)

If that does help you, I will use it to create a valid answer here.

Comment: i can't even go into xampp control panel, how am i going to configure it change the ports

Comment: Hmm... it talks about editing the file `http.conf` or so - there is something about the panel, but maybe it's only for finding the file. Can you try? By the way, how are you running it? As which user? Your exception is from a null pointer, but could be it followed from a problem of not getting port 80 - you need root permissions to access ports up to 1024.

Comment: actually i installed the xampp s/w in the window server 2003 and i am able to go to localhost/xampp to create database. once run the software, nothing can be seen just disappeared like that